# How to capture the index of an array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a problem with a capturing the index.

The error is in the following part of code:

```
for i=2:1:7
    for j=1:1:64
        for k=1:1:64
            if (n0(j,:)==data(k,:))%capturing the index of n0 using the table of data
                n0d=k    ;  %n0d stores captured index                   
            end
%             n0d
        end
        
        for m=1:1:64
            if(n1(j,:)==data(m,:))%capturing the index of n1 using the table of data
                n1d=m; %n1d stores capured index
            end
            n1d
        end
        if (~(predecessor(n0d,(i-1))==flag) | ~(predecessor(n1d,(i-1))==flag))
            if(predecessor(n0d,(i-1))~=flag)
            predecessor(j,i)=n0d-1;
            else
                predecessor(j,i)=n1d-1;
            end
        end
    end
    
end
```

Matlab error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'n0d'.

Error in vc_test (line 89)
        if (~(predecessor(n0d,(i-1))==flag) | ~(predecessor(n1d,(i-1))==flag))
```

I didnt see any mistake in the code. could someone explain why  `n0d=k`  doesnt work?

EDIT 1: [original code](https://github.com/radhikamathuria25/Soft-Viterbi-Decoder-for-IRNSS/blob/d40afbec002afa6261832e3bff002937a7f3d8f3/Viterbi_decoder_length7.m)

Comment: n0d=k is inside an if, I guess it's because the if conditions is not fulfil so n0d doesn't exist.

Comment: @PedroRodriguez I thought about it. I checked the first two if-blocks give me a result. Matlab doesnt use the captured valued in the 3rd block

Comment: @StewieGriffin I compare char data

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It seems the use of breakpoints or other debug methods would help you to understand your problem better, I highly recommend you to read [how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)